# how to parameterize tablename in mybatis

Tags: mybatis

I want to parameterize table_name:t_user_address_book(uid/500000).
for example: when uid = 1000, table_name = t_user_address_book0;
when uid = 500001, table_name = t_user_address_book1;
How to write?

```
public interface UserAddressBookMapper {
    @Insert("insert into t_user_address_book? values(...)")
    int upsert(Long uid, UserAddressBookMsg userAddressBookMsg);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can choose the table with Mybatis XML code:

```
<choose>
  <when test="uid gt 1000000">
    <bind name="tableName" value="t_user_address_book2" />
  </when>
  <when test="uid gt 500000">
    <bind name="tableName" value="t_user_address_book1" />
  </when>
  <otherwise>
    <bind name="tableName" value="t_user_address_book0" />
  </otherwise>
</choose>
```

Or you can compute the table name in the java and pass it as parameter.

Whatever your choice, the table name parameter in the query must be referenced with the `$` notation instead of `#` since the value must replace the place holder as is to be part of the query and not being interpreted/bound/escaped as parameters are:

```
INSERT INTO ${tableName} ...
```

Despite use of XML, you can stick with annotations surrounding the query with `<script>` tags:

```
@Insert({"<script>", 
         "<choose> ...", 
         "INSERT ..."
         "</script>"
})
```

Also when using Mapper interface with annotations, you need to name the parameters with there are more than 1:

```
@Insert("INSERT INTO table VALUES(#{uid}, #{userAddressBookMsg.propertyName1})")
int upsert(upsert(@Param("uid")Long uid, @Param("userAddressBookMsg") UserAddressBookMsg userAddressBookMsg);
```

However, it seems you want to split into multiple tables for volume issues, this is much complexity to handle while it would better be to keep a single table and look around on DB side about indexing and partitioning.

Answer (score -2):

Quick response will be "no". It is not possible to give table name as parameter, because mybatis uses prepared statements.

I would suggest using table name as variable, and giving it to the statement string.
For example:

```
public interface UserAddressBookMapper { 

static String tableName;
static void setTableName(String name) {
  tableName = name;
}

@Insert({"insert into", tableName, "values(...)"})
int upsert(UserAddressBookMsg userAddressBookMsg);
```

You will have to set `tableName` before calling the method.

Comment: first statement is totally false and code snippet does not compile, it cannot: uninitialized static field +  method with body in an interface